# Is there an alternative to MySQL Field() function in VFP?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a multi fields table with a Countries column. I like the results from a query to be ordered by a particular country first and the rest alphabetically. In MySQL I would do something like:

```
Select * from myTable Order By Field(Countries,'Italy'),Countries
```

In Visual-FoxPro I have tried indexing the Cursor created by this query:

```
Select * from myTable Order By Countries

Index on Countries<>'Italy' TAG test
```

This would display all results for 'Italy' first, but leave the rest in an unpredictable order.
How to achieve this in Visual-FoxPro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VFP you can do it with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Countries='Italy' ;
UNION ALL ;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Countries<>'Italy' ORDER BY Countries) as secsel
```

Comment: wow both answers  work and make sense! I am choosing Fer B just because he come in first...thank you guys. Nice to see VFP still alive

Answer (score 1):

It does order by "if countries is not Italy first then Italy", Countries. Right?

In VFP you can use IIF(). ie:

```
Select *, iif(Countries == 'Italy', 1, 0) as CItaly ;
 from myTable :
 Order By CItaly,Countries
```

Note: If you want to do this via an index then you can use a composite index like:

```
index on iif(Countries = 'Italy', '1', '0') + Countries tag myCountry
```